# How would I print martini glass pattern in c# optimal way

Tags: c#, algorithm, console-application

I am trying to print the martini glass pattern using c#.
The pattern is like following:

for input = 4;

```
0000000
 00000
  000
   0
   |
   |
   |
   |
=======
```

for input = 5;

```
000000000
 0000000
  00000
   000
    0
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
=========
```

I am able to get till triangle(0's).However, I am failing to get the neck(|) and bottom(=).

My code looks as follows:

```
        const int height = 4;
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            //left padding
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(' ');
            }

            for (int col = 0; col < (height - row) * 2 - 1; col++)
            {

                Console.Write('0');
            }
            //right padding
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('|');
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

And it prints like this:

```
0000000
 00000
  000
   0
|||
```

Can somebody help me in finishing the neck and the bottom?
And also is my code optimal? You are free to edit the complete code for optimization.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:
Code added for neck and bottom:

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            // Left padding
            for (int j = 1; j < height; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
            Console.WriteLine('|');
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            {
                Console.Write('=');
            }
        }

      Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string constructor is helpful to avoid writing excessive loops

```
int count = 5;
for(int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('0', 2*i + 1).PadLeft(i+count));
}
Console.Write(new string('|', count).Replace("|","|\n".PadLeft(count+1)));
Console.WriteLine(new string('=', count* 2-1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `string` class constructor to repeat a pattern instead of looping them over.

```
class HelloWorld {
    static void Main() {
        const int height = 1 ;
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            var spaces = new String(' ', row);
            var zeroes = new String('0', ((height - row) * 2 ) -1 );
            Console.WriteLine(spaces + zeroes);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            var spaces = new String(' ', height -1);
            Console.WriteLine(spaces + '|');
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new String('=', (height *2) -1));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

**Edit**

But optimal I'm assuming faster execution time. But for relatively smaller values I do not see how the both could make a significant difference. But I still ran it on BenchmarkDotNet

First refer's to my code and Second is kazem's one.

I am not sure what to make out of this output. But I assume you can read more on it from [their documentation](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/Guides/GettingStarted.htm#step-3.-view-results)

```
// * Detailed results *
MartiniBenchMark.First: DefaultJob
Runtime = .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 1.7365 ms, StdErr = 0.0081 ms (0.47%); N = 15, StdDev = 0.0315 ms
Min = 1.6916 ms, Q1 = 1.7099 ms, Median = 1.7309 ms, Q3 = 1.7626 ms, Max = 1.8087 ms
IQR = 0.0527 ms, LowerFence = 1.6309 ms, UpperFence = 1.8417 ms
ConfidenceInterval = [1.7028 ms; 1.7702 ms] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0337 ms (1.94% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.45, Kurtosis = 2.58


MartiniBenchMark.Second: DefaultJob
Runtime = .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 1.8580 ms, StdErr = 0.0147 ms (0.79%); N = 96, StdDev = 0.1440 ms
Min = 1.6291 ms, Q1 = 1.7440 ms, Median = 1.8311 ms, Q3 = 1.9782 ms, Max = 2.2573 ms
IQR = 0.2342 ms, LowerFence = 1.3927 ms, UpperFence = 2.3295 ms
ConfidenceInterval = [1.8081 ms; 1.9079 ms] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0499 ms (2.69% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.42, Kurtosis = 2.22


Total time: 00:12:04 (724.8 sec)

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.9, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 1 (10.0.14393)
Processor=Intel Core i3-3110M CPU 2.40GHz (Ivy Bridge), ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=2338445 Hz, Resolution=427.6346 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0


 Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
  First | 1.737 ms | 0.0337 ms | 0.0315 ms |
 Second | 1.858 ms | 0.0499 ms | 0.1440 ms |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  MartiniBenchMark.First: Default  -> 3 outliers were removed
  MartiniBenchMark.Second: Default -> 4 outliers were removed

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  1 ms   : 1 Millisecond (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Out of these two solutions which are optimal?

Comment: Also, in the second `for` loop, shouldn't `i` start at `0`? Otherwise it will print one less than the expected output.

Comment: You're right again. IT wouldn't print anything when height is 1.

Comment: In terms of which ones are optimal, test them. This could be done simply using the StopWatch class. Start it before running the code and then stop it again. Which one is faster? Increase the size of the input value and test again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the spaces in the left first. Just as the same you did in case of '0'. `Left Padding` part.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
{
    // Left padding
    for(int j = 1; j < height; j++)
    {
         Console.Write(' ');
    }
    Console.WriteLine('|');
}
```

And your neck loop should go till `<=height`.

Now, I think you can complete the bottom part.(It will be same as the first line of '0', without any padding) Please let me know if you face any difficulty.

Also, I don't think you need Right padding part.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
Bottom Part:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= height * 2 - 1; i++)
{
    Console.Write("=");
}
```

Comment: With this code, I am able to get the neck part correctly but the bottom is slightly left sided.I feel it should be a bit right sided.Please see the edited part in my Question

Comment: Out of these two solutions which are optimal?

Comment: You do not need a nested loop for the bottom part. Only i loop should be enough. See my edit.

Comment: I think calling a string constructor will be more optimal, because it doesn't connect to the Console repeatedly. I think the Answer by `thebenman` is more optimal than this one. But I also think if we use a string builder and append all of these into it. And finally print to console, it would have been better. @Santosh